# What does this definition mean? (Affine Spaces)

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

$$P:=\{(0,0,0)+\alpha e_1 + \beta e_2 + \gamma e_3 , \alpha + \beta + \gamma \in [0,1]\}\subset A$$

Hey,

I'm having trouble understanding this definition. We are currently doing affine spaces in our lectures and this is one definition for an exercise. The text says that $e_1,e_2,e_3$ and $(0,0,0)$ span a polygon but I don't know how to imagine. When I try to imagine, I think of three vectors coming from $(0,0,0)$ but they would span a something like a cube. Where is my fallacy?

I'm thankful for any kind of help! ;)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott We know that $0\le\alpha+\beta+\gamma\le1$ but not $\alpha\ge0$, etc.  I describe the figure as a closed slab.

Comment: I agree with @kimchilover. It's a "thick plane" with normal $(1,1,1).$ Probably the author meant to also have conditions $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \geq 0.$ Then it becomes a tetrahedron with corners in $(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1).$

Comment: No the professor said that they can be any real number. But then you can't say where the tetrahedron is. How could you then describe affine transformation like translations on it?

Comment: But why does the thick plane becomes a tetrahedron when the scales are bigger than zero?